# how to make jmeter output graphs

Tags: graph, jmeter

I am not a jmeter expert, but I understand it can display graphs and save the data in .xml files.

Is there a way to have jmeter actually create JPG, GIF or PNG files (or whatever format that can be embedded in html?)

**Added later:** I need a solution that works in a batch run

Comment: Hi, I think you should maybe change the accepted answer to one that fits your "batch run mode". Thanks

Comment: @flybywire - Were you able to figure out this one? I need to do something similar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way would be to right click on a Graph Result to "Save Node as Image".

Comment: Not the best answer as of JMeter 2.11 and jmeter plugins 1.1.3

Comment: In Jmeter 2.11 and up it's called "Save image as"

Answer (score 4):

Use [Loadosophia](http://loadosophia.org) or [jmeter-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/)

Answer (score 3):

I would stand by @Andrey Pohilko in agreeing that [Loadosophia](http://loadosophia.org/) is the best when it comes to graphs and also jmeter-plugins for addons for jmeter tool.

Check out the sample loadosophia graph [here.](https://loadosophia.org/examples/5062/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest saving as a CSV file, then using a graphing engine separately to generate graphs.  If you want to create them dynamically you could use some open-source graphing tools and a workflow engine.

If you're happy with doing it by hand, Excel?

Answer (score 1):

there is a list of ways to analyze logs on the wiki - http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/LogAnalysis

I use jmetergraph.pl for nice summary reports.
Note that there is a bug with the default jmetergraph.pl, you need to add this to line 313, at the end of the while loop:

```
    close(IN);
}

$glabels{'entire'} = \%entire;    # this line added.
print "Found $#labels labels\n" if $DEBUG;
```

Otherwise you can use the jmeterlog class to create your own images by writing custom code for it.....

Answer (score 1):

Use JMeter-plugins and the listener called JP@GC Graphs Generator:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/

In upcoming version 2.14 or 3.0, there will be this new feature that generate an HTML report with dynamic graphs, APDEX table and summary of errors:

- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Donation-of-a-New-Dashboard-for-JMeter-Questions-and-more-td5723379.html

It is available in nightly build as of 20th january 2016:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html